# How do I call a function from the same file as I would if using getattr?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

In my program I have 25 different functions named `"task1"`, `"task2"`, `"task3"`, etc...
At the moment I can call on these functions from a separate file and do them in the shell:

```
import examplefilename
tasknum = str(input("Which task would you like to see? "))
task = "task" + tasknum
methodToCall = getattr(examplefilename, task)
result = methodToCall()
```

What I have done will only call from a different file though so how do I do a function in this manner from the same file?

Comment: in python 3 you don't need to call `str` to the `input` because it is already a string, and in python 2 you should use `raw_input` instead

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, the functions are defined in the same file and you need user input to invoke them, just use `globals` instead of `getattr`.

That is, replace the `getattr` with:

```
methodToCall = globals()[task]  # it isn't a method, though
```

keeping the rest as-is.

As also noted in a comment, wrapping `input` with `str` is superfluous here, `input` already returns a string.